# How to list coding/noncoding genomic regions linked to significant SNPs?

Tags: genetics, snp, gwas

For QTL analysis in mice [GEMMA](https://github.com/genetics-statistics/GEMMA) was used to get P values ("p_lrt" column) for SNPs. GEMMA output (...assoc.txt) file excerpt:

```
chr  rs           ps       n_miss  allele1  allele0  af     logl_H1        l_mle         p_lrt  
1    UNC6         3010274  45      T        C        0.753  -1.871575e+03  9.092954e+00  4.497885e-01  
1    JAX00240613  3323400  12      T        C        0.766  -1.871777e+03  9.096464e+00  6.822045e-01  
...
```

Then, drawing a Manhattan plot with [qqman](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qqman/vignettes/qqman.html) R package applies default suggestive/genomewide cutoffs. But if I get it right, P < 5×10^(−8) is a commonly used genomewide threshold [Ref1](https://www.nature.com/articles/ejhg2015269), [Ref2](https://academic.oup.com/g3journal/article/11/2/jkaa056/6080665).

Then I have to list the relevant coding/noncoding regions linked to these significant SNP (with P < 5×10^(−8)).
How can I do this?

I found a fantastic tool called [FUMA](https://fuma.ctglab.nl/)
but it seems for GWAS in humans not for QTL analysis.

Update:
In Karl Browman's presentations: [pdf](https://www.biostat.wisc.edu/%7Ekbroman/teaching/misc/SISG/2003/intro_ho.pdf) (p. 13); [pdf](https://www.biostat.wisc.edu/%7Ekbroman/teaching/misc/Jax/2016/intro.pdf) (p. 23(=28), 29(=34), 30(=35)).

Comment: GEMMA should give you confidence/credible intervals no? Also please expand on what you mean by ‘gene candidates’, that’s a bit of a vague term.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest seeing what others have done when using GEMMA. For example, you can see [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-07642-8#MOESM4)'s methods:

> We converted p-values to LOD scores and used a 1.5-LOD support interval to approximate a critical region around each associated region, which enabled us to systematically identify overlap with eQTLs.

They further discuss this approach in the supplementary note:

> Instead we converted p-values
> to LOD scores and used a 1.5-LOD support interval to approximate a critical region around each
> association. The LOD drop approach provides a quick, straightforward way to gauge mapping precision
> and systematically identify overlap between eQTL genes and candidate QTGs; however, it does not
> correspond to a specific confidence interval (e.g. 95% confidence interval).

I would suggest trying something like this to estimate such a "critical region". For a discussion of the relationship between LOD and p-values, a quick search yielded [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1287176/).